# How do I integrate the differential equation?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative, chemistry

I have an equation from chemistry:
$$\frac{\delta (\frac{\Delta G}{T})}{\delta T}=-\frac{\Delta H}{T^2}$$
This is known as the [Gibbs-Helmholtz equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs%E2%80%93Helmholtz_equation).

Now according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs%E2%80%93Helmholtz_equation), if I integrate this, I would get:
$$\frac{\Delta G_{T_2}}{T_2}-\frac{\Delta G_{T_1}}{T_1}=\Delta H(\frac{1}{T_2} -\frac{1}{T_1})$$
Now, this makes sense, however, I watched another [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HgLdBZsbDQY&list=PLtY1wJId77gLP1Y1I5dWsndeBE4TF2hY9&index=9) on the same thing on YouTube and that gives a slightly different answer. It uses $\Delta H_{T_1}$ as in, the $\Delta H$ at $T_1$ only and not $\Delta H$ in general which I suppose considers both $T_1$ and $T_2$, i.e., $\Delta H=\Delta H_{T_2}-\Delta H_{T_1}$. But I am not quite sure. Can someone tell me which source is correct?

If anyone thinks it will be helpful, $\Delta G$ is the Gibbs free energy, $T$ is the temperature, $\Delta H$ is the change in enthalpy, and naturally, $T_1$ is the initial temperature and $T_2$ is the final temperature.

Comment: I think the Wikipedia result is correct, as by integrating the equation both sides w.r.t. $T$ from $T_1$ to $T_2$, we can easily derive the result.

Comment: Why don't you use UNIFAC for an estimation of $\Delta H_{mix}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be correct if $\Delta H$ was a constant, which is not true.

Assume a simple polynomial dependency such as
$$\Delta H=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i\, T^i$$ and, for the antiderivative, you will have
$$\frac{\Delta G} T=-\int  a_i\, T^{i-2}\,dT$$ that is to say
$$\frac{\Delta G} T=\frac{a_0}T-a_1 \log(T)-\sum_{i=2}^n \frac{a_i}i T^{i-1}$$ and here you see coming the famous $T\log(T)$ term.

Now, use the bounds.

Comment: The original differential equation mentioned in the question is derived considering that $\Delta H$ is a function of $T$, watch this video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RpwYXwmssiw) for further clarity. So I don't see how logs come into the case.

Comment: @noobanomaly. I cannot watch the video since I am blind. By the way, I am thermodynamicist.

Comment: I am not questioning your knowledge... you have a reputation of 200k so I am sure you know more math (and chemistry it seems) than me, I simply mean to clarify my doubt and I wasn't sure how ΔH is not being considered as a variable in the initial case itself.

Comment: @noobanomaly. I am not sarcastic at all (alas !). But, back to the problem, what they do is implicitely assuming that $\DeltaH$ is not a constant. But, they ignore the path. This is what I wrote which is more general. Think about the area under the curve : what they use is a trapezoid while I suggest to follow the curve.

Comment: Ahh alright, please forgive me for my rash behaviour, the internet is a weird place. Coming back to the question, in my case, I am talking about the $\Delta H_{mix}$, so would that not be constant? What I have done is, I took two solutions and prepared a real solution where $\Delta H_{mix}$ is not 0. I have also measured the temperature changes. In this case I would have a constant value for $\Delta H_{mix}$, right?

Comment: @noobanomaly. It is not a constant. In general, we compute it using equations of state or liquid activity models or both combined. If $T_1$ and $T_2$ are close to each other. If you don't have more information about the mixture, keep $\Delta H_{mix}=Cte$.